# views, buttons in nsscrollview not appearing anymore

Tags: objective-c, button, addition, subview, nsscrollview

In my Xcode4 projects I was using the Interface Builder to add scrollviews to my xibs.
After that I could drag other buttons or views into that scrollview so that they
appeared as expected when the app started. Strangely after switching to Mavericks and Xcode5 neither the buttons nor views appear after dragging them onto the scrollview in IB. So without changes from my side the projects using scrollviews don't work correctly anymore. Before starting the app everything looks the same. In the IB Document-Outline they are shown after Clip-View. Like this: ->scrollview ->clipview ->nsview_iwant_to_add. The buttons and views are shown in the IB preview.

Anyone an idea? Should be easy to reproduce. Just drag a scrollview to a xib and drag another (colored)view/button onto that scrollview to see they're not appearing in the running application.

Comment: Add some `NSLog()` calls to various subclassed methods of your custom view, like `awakeFromNib`, `setFrameSize:` (make sure you call `[super setFrameSize:]`), and `drawRect:`, etc.

Comment: I have this issue also using just the standard classes. New project->add scrollview to xib->drag button onto the scrollview->start the app-->no button shown

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding constraints to the elements put in nsscrollview. min. width height. etc.
The problem seems to be related to the way autolayout treats objects inside the scrollview.